# Crystal Reports and multiple tables

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, crystal-reports

I'm using C# and Entity Framework.
I created the dataset to display data from it:
[image]

With only one table(buildings), i created my crystal report very well.
But now, i want to create another one that display:

- name_b, Adresse_b,date
- the number of appartements of a building
- the number of shared_areas of a building
- and the name of the user.

I have to write a query in the crystalReportViewer1_Load and set it as datasource or what?
Thank you to help me.

Comment: `Another one?` in the same report or new report?

Comment: i want to show it in the same report

Comment: you can create sub report and if first datasource has all these columns then you can use the same datasource and create else create new datasource

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options - 
 1. In your current report, group the report by Building, then
    create a sub-report containing all of the details (name,
    address,etc) and place it into the group footer in the main (outer)
    report. Link the report by ID_Building. This will show you all of
    the details for each building. 
 2. In you current report, add all of the tables to the data connection (database expert); then group the report as desired (by building, Apartment, etc).

You can create running totals to get the count of apartments and the number of shared_areas.